# Logisim MUX selection

Tags: logisim

I have designed a 4x1 MUX. I want to give the selection from two diferent inputs and not one 2bit input. How can I do that, if possible?

In the image you see the "incompatible widths" error which is expected:

[image]

```
              |\
              | \ 
   (input):(--|  |O--- ... (output)
              | / 
              |/
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use some kind of IO component that would let you **merge** two or more signals into one signal with greater width. That should be enough of a hint.